# HTTPS in request and HTTP in response

Tags: tls, http, web-service

If I have an API that calls a backend webservice, is it possible to use HTTPS in the request and just HTTP in the response?

I have such a question because I want to protect my OAuth token in my request. And then use WS-Security in my SOAP response. I am trying to find a way to get these two things work together as it seems WS-Security cannot work with HTTPS...

Comment: You would have to establish two separate TCP connections.  Not sure why you wouldn't just use HTTPS for both directions.

Comment: HTTP is a request-response protocol by definition. I'm not understanding what you mean by this question.

Answer (score 2):

No - the whole connection would either be over HTTP or HTTPS - request and response.

I can't think of a situation where encryption would be required for the request but not for the response - there is no advantage to this since the SSL handshake would have to take place anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have such a question because I want to protect my OAuth token in my request. And then use WS-Security in my SOAP response.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you would want to do such a thing - but no, it is not possible. HTTPS is HTTP over TLS, so as soon as there is a TLS connection established, all non-encrypted traffic should be discarded by the TLS stack immediately.

What you could do however, is respond with a location header (redirect) and point to a HTTP-document, if your software follows redirects.